# Django: "argument of type 'int' is not iterable" in oracle/base.py in _rowfactory

Tags: python, django, oracle, apache

I'm trying to connect my Django app to Oracle DB but making a query results in exception:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Exception Location: /opt/isep/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py in _rowfactory, line 560

```
def _rowfactory(row, cursor):
# Cast numeric values as the appropriate Python type based upon the
# cursor description, and convert strings to unicode.
casted = []
for value, desc in zip(row, cursor.description):
    if value is not None and desc[1] is Database.NUMBER:
        precision = desc[4] or 0
        scale = desc[5] or 0
        if scale == -127:
            if precision == 0:
                # NUMBER column: decimal-precision floating point
                # This will normally be an integer from a sequence,
                # but it could be a decimal value.
                if '.' in value:
                    value = decimal.Decimal(value)
                else:
                    value = int(value)
            else:
                # FLOAT column: binary-precision floating point.
                # This comes from FloatField columns.
                value = float(value)
        elif precision > 0:
            # NUMBER(p,s) column: decimal-precision fixed point.
            # This comes from IntField and DecimalField columns.
            if scale == 0:
                value = int(value)
            else:
                value = decimal.Decimal(value)
        elif '.' in value:
            # No type information. This normally comes from a
            # mathematical expression in the SELECT list. Guess int
            # or Decimal based on whether it has a decimal point.
            value = decimal.Decimal(value)
        else:
            value = int(value)
    elif desc[1] in (Database.STRING, Database.FIXED_CHAR,
                     Database.LONG_STRING):
        value = to_unicode(value)
    casted.append(value)
return tuple(casted)
```

Error occurs in line: `if '.' in value:` because `value = 0`.

I'm using: Python 3.4, Django 1.11, cx_Oracle 6.0.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you please provide an example query to further investigate the issue?

Comment: Just simple Django's Model.objects.all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I've removed my venv and then created another one. This time I installed Django 1.11.15 and cx_Oracle 6.0. Everything seems to be working fine. Exception is gone.